# facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions with Firebase issues

Tags: swift, firebase, facebook-login, firebase-authentication

I am able to successfully authenticate login with facebook using basic SDK procedures, but am having some confusion when I am trying to authenticate with Firebase. I have read through the documentation and copied and pasted the code but I am still getting a warning that reads

```
'logInWithReadPermissions(_:handler:)' is deprecated: use logInWithReadPermissions:fromViewController:handler: instead facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], handler: instead.
```

1) What does this warning mean and how do I fix it? 
2) With emails and password sign in you see the registered users created, but how do I know and see if users were registered with facebook authentication in the Firebase DB?

Thanks for any help or direction!

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

    let loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton = {
        let button = FBSDKLoginButton()
        button.readPermissions = ["email"]
        return button
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(loginButton)
        loginButton.center = view.center
        loginButton.delegate = self

        let ref = Firebase(url: "https://my-app.firebaseio.com")
        let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()

        facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], handler: {
            (facebookResult, facebookError) -> Void in
            if facebookError != nil {
                print("Facebook login failed. Error \(facebookError)")
            } else if facebookResult.isCancelled {
                print("Facebook login was cancelled.")
            } else {
                let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString
                ref.authWithOAuthProvider("facebook", token: accessToken,
                    withCompletionBlock: { error, authData in
                        if error != nil {
                            print("Login failed. \(error)")
                        } else {
                            print("Logged in! \(authData)")
                        }
                })
            }
        })

    }


    func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
        if error == nil {
            print("completed login")
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showNew", sender: self)
        }

        else {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }


    func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
        print("user logged out")
    }

    func loginButtonWillLogin(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: check this for silent the warnings http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32048964/fbsdkloginmanager-code-from-objective-c-to-swift/32049197#32049197

Comment: Facebook is added one more parameter : http://stackoverflow.com/a/33208089/3202193 check this answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like (compiles without warnings to me):

```
let currentToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()

    // Show login only if we had not logged in before
    if (currentToken == nil || !currentToken.hasGranted("email")) {

        let ref = Firebase(url: "https://my-app.firebaseio.com")
        let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()
        facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self, handler: {
            (facebookResult, facebookError) -> Void in
            if facebookError != nil {
                log.error("Facebook login failed. Error \(facebookError)")
.
.
.
```